# How can I hide an E4Application application

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, e4

I have an instance of "org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application" , that i want to execute in the background (headless app:  No task bar icon and No GUI).

Comment: I don't think this is possible, see Eclipse bug [323075](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=323075)

Answer (score 0):

getshell().setVisible("false");